# Unable to install ShareJS with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, sharejs

Using VM (vagrant) Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.
npm and nodeJS versions are up to date.

I'm trying to install shareJS via

```
sudo npm install share@"<0.7"
```

but this cause npm errors.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "share@<0.7"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.1
npm ERR! path ../coffee-script/bin/coffee
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71

npm ERR! EPROTO, symlink '../coffee-script/bin/coffee'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "share@<0.7"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.1
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.8eb898407f81b59ca45e8e0a6a951820
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
```

Thought that problem with versions of node or npm, reinstalled them but that's did no effect. 
Also look similar to licence expired issue, but it was closed month ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add --no-bin-links flag.

```
npm install --no-bin-links  share@"<0.7"
```

Hope thats would be usefull for someone.

Answer (score 0):

i just copied you  command   and it worked for me .

My machine is :

Ubuntu 14.4   64 bit

Node js  version : v0.10.38
Npm version :   2.9.0

i think you  have to check  with this  versions. 
please check is your version match wit this.

Good Luck

Comment: earlier I tryed to install with older versions (node 0.10.25, npm 0.11.) and there were another errors.
Also tryed to install with windows node JS and it worked. 
idk what had happend to my machine.